# Using `sendto()` on a IPv6 socket to send to a IPv4 address

Tags: sockets, portability, ipv6, freebsd, ipv4

I have a C++ application that uses the same IPv6 UDP socket to send to IPv6 or IPv4 destinations.

```c++
sockfd = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
dest_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin6_port = htons(dest_port);
inet_pton ("192.168.1.33",  &dest_addr.sin6_addr);
sendto (sockfd, message, strlen(message)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
```

On Linux this works fine, but on FreeBSD I get an error `Address family not supported by protocol family` when I send to IPv4 addresses.

Is there a way to configure FreeBSD to accept this?
Maybe similar to `ipv6_ipv4mapping="YES"` for listening to IPv4 clients?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have a socket for ipv4 and one for ipv6?

Comment: @Paolo: Two reasons a.) it fits the existing (IPv4 based) program  structure well and b.) the application already uses many hundreds of sockets and I'd prefer not to double it.

Comment: in C++ you only need `(sockaddr *)`, not `(struct sockaddr *)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an IPv6 socket, so you have to use IPv6 addresses.  However, if your OS supports dual-stack sockets (ie, natively supports both IPv4 and IPv6 on a single socket), then use an [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) to send to an IPv4 address (if the OS allows it, some do not). Otherwise, you have to use separate sockets for IPv4 annd IPv6.

Comment: Linux doesn't seem to see it that way and the code works fine. I was hoping that FreeBSD would have a switch to be a bit more relaxed.

Comment: @GeneVincent - I'm not familiar with FreeBSD, but I was under the impression changing it to `inet_pton("::ffff:192.168.1.33", &dest....);` should work on FreeBSD

Comment: @awoodland: Sure that works, but that means converting each address. A system wide switch to the Linux behavior would have suited my needs better, but I guess I'll have to go with the conversion.

Comment: @GeneVincent - my suggestion would be to replace calls to `inet_pton` with your own function that can insert the `"::ffff:"` as needed.