# AF_INET6 socket and IPv4 addr

Tags: udp, ipv6

I want to send UDP data to both IPv4 and IPv6 clients. If I create an AF_INET6 unbound socket on the sender (`socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`), can I pass both AF_INET and AF_INET6 addrs to the sendto() function, as the destination address?

```
// Is this correct?
sin->sin_family = AF_INET;
sendto(socket, data, size, 0,
(struct sockaddr*)&sin,
(socklen_t)sizeof(sin)
```

And

```
// This should be correct
sin6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
sendto(socket, data, size, 0,
(struct sockaddr*)&sin6,
(socklen_t)sizeof(sin6)
```

Is it any different if I pass a sockaddr_storage to the sendto(), on which I have beforehand set the family to either AF_INET or AF_INET6 (via corresponding casting)?

```
//is this correct?
struct sockaddr_in * sin = (struct sockaddr_in*)s_storageAddr
sin->sin_family = AF_INET;
sendto(socket, data, size, 0,
(struct sockaddr*)&s_storageAddr,
(socklen_t)sizeof(s_storageAddr)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to support both IPv4 and IPv6 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618240/how-to-support-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-connections), [Using `sendto()` on a IPv6 socket to send to a IPv4 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087478/using-sendto-on-a-ipv6-socket-to-send-to-a-ipv4-address)

Comment: I'm aware of the IPv4-mapped option, but I want to ask specifically about the above.

Comment: The socket expects a IPv6 address, so you have to provide one - even if it is a mapped IPv4